# $G$ nilpotent of class $c$ and derived length $d\;\Rightarrow d\le1+\log_2c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotence

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group of class $c$ and derived length $d$.

Then $d\le1+\log_2c$.

What we want to do is prove that this result can't be improved.

So I considered the group $C_p\wr C_p$ i.e. the wreath product of $C_p$ and $C_p$. We know that this group has nilpotence class equal to $p$.

Then I'm trying to prove that its derived length it's equal to $2$.

The only idea came to my mind is to use Ito Theorem (if a group $G$ can be written as $AB$ where $A$ and $B$ are abelian group, then $G^{(2)}=1$, i.e. $d\le2$); but if I really can take account of this theorem, who are the two abelian groups $A$ and $B$?

Comment: You probably mean $C_p \wr C_p = (C_p)^p \rtimes C_p$. It is much smaller than the group you wrote, and works just as well. It should also make answering your question easier for you.

Comment: Exactly; I edited. So the groups $A$ and $B$ are $(C_p)^p$ and $C_p$ respectively, right? I.e. $C_p\wr C_p\simeq (C_p)^{p+1}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: A standard wreath product $A \wr B$ has a  normal subgroup $N \cong A^{|B|}$ with $G/N \cong B$. So if $A$ and $B$ are both abelian, then $N$ is abelian, and $A \wr B$ has derived length 2. (But I don't see how this will help you show that the bound on derived length cannot be improved.)

Comment: Thanks: in this way we'd have a group of class $p$ and length $2$; just take $p=2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I thank you for your answer but I can't understand how you got the conclusion "... and $A\wr B$ has derived length $2$"!

Comment: @JackSchmidt: clearly $C_p\wr C_p$ is NOT isomorphic to $(C_p)^{p+1}$ since in such a case it would be abelian!

Comment: @Joe: I don't understand why you directed that comment to me. Certainly $C_p \wr C_p$ is not isomorphic to $(C_p)^{p+1}$. It is isomorphic to $(C_p)^p \rtimes C_p$.

Comment: Ok ok solved. $G/N\simeq B$ hence $G/B$ is abelian, hence $G'\le N$; but $N$ abelian implies $G'$ abelian, so derived length of $G'$ is $1$ and by def. $d=2$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: it's a misunderstanding! I wrote to you because before I wrote to you that wrong thing. It's like saying "ok man, I understood I wrote a wrong fact"... nothing more

Comment: @Joe: Gotcha. Yes, your choice of $A$ and $B$ are correct. You are also now correct that Ito's lemma is not even needed. You are also now correct that $G$ is definitely not abelian. :-)